# Convert txt file to csv with lambda s3 Aws

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have this code that must pass a file from a TXT type source bucket and must convert it to CSV in a destination bucket, it returns as a response that the variable or object (z) that should contain the CSV file cannot be opened because it is null. It seems that the code that I use is not transforming the object correctly. Please, I need help to correct it.

- The code is the following:

import pandas as pd
import json
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

def lambda_handler(evenBytesIOt,context):

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
source_bucket = 'testsigma2'
target_bucket = 'testsigma3'

my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket)

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if(str(file.key).endswith('.txt')):
        
       zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=source_bucket, key=file.key)
       
       buffer= BytesIO(zip_obj.get()['Body'].read())
       
       dataframe1=pd.read_csv(buffer)
       z = dataframe1.to_csv(buffer,index=None) 
       
       response = s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
                    z.open(filename),
                    Bucket = target_bucket,
                    key = f'{filename}'

                )

    else:
        print(file.key + 'is not a zip file.')
```

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 25, in lambda_handler\n    z.open(filename),\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: the pandas.to_csv() function returns none,  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html so z has value None, i think you need to use buffer directly

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this, what would the code be like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to open the z object after calling the to_csv method, but the to_csv method does not return a file object. Instead, it writes the CSV data directly to the buffer object that you provided as an argument. You can confirm this by calling the seek method on the buffer object after calling to_csv to reset the position of the file pointer to the beginning of the file:

```
dataframe1=pd.read_csv(buffer)
z = dataframe1.to_csv(buffer,index=None) 

//Reset the position of the file pointer to the beginning of the file
buffer.seek(0)

response = s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
             buffer,
             Bucket = target_bucket,
             key = f'{filename}'
          )
```

You can then use the buffer object as the file object to be uploaded to S3.

Comment: It works but now I get key error try to fix it with Key=f'{filename}' which is not predefined in the code but I can't find the way to extract the key from the file

Answer (score 0):

The `to_csv` method on a pandas dataframe doesn't return the buffer, instead it returns none and writes to the buffer `buffer`. Thus when it returns `None` and you try and open `filename` it will error. try passing the `buffer` to the `upload_fileobj`. Additionally, I don't think `filename` is defined anywhere so be aware of that.

For documentation on the specific resources your using, check this out:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html
df